# How can I write to my ID3D11UnorderedAccessView's buffer before dispatching my shader?

Tags: c++, shader, directx-11

Let's say I have

```
ID3D11UnorderedAccessView* pDataView
```

and I have

```
byte* pRawData
```

how can I set pDataView's buffer with pRawData?

NOTE: FAILED and CHR are error checking-macros.

UPDATE: Soonts gave an answer that seems to do the trick when I'm creating the UAV, but in the interest of completeness I'd also like to be able to successfully update its buffer from the CPU after both have been created.  I've not been so successful trying that.  If I have:

```
        template <typename T>
        static inline void CreateUnorderedAccessViewFromFile(
            _In_ ID3D11Device* pDevice,
            _In_ ID3D11DeviceContext* pDeviceContext,
            _In_ HANDLE dataFile,
            _Out_ ID3D11Buffer** ppBuffer,
            _Out_ ID3D11UnorderedAccessView** ppUav)
        {
            uint64_t fileSize;

            //CBR(::GetFileSizeEx(handle, &fileSize));
            //Custom size for testing purposes
            fileSize = 0x800;

            D3D11_BUFFER_DESC bufferDesc =
            {
                fileSize, // ByteWidth
                D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT, // Usage
                D3D11_BIND_UNORDERED_ACCESS, // BindFlags
                D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE, // CPUAccessFlags
                D3D11_RESOURCE_MISC_BUFFER_STRUCTURED, // MiscFlags
                sizeof(T), // StructureByteStride
            };

            CHR(pDevice->CreateBuffer(
                &bufferDesc,
                nullptr,
                ppBuffer));


            D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE mappedResource;

            HRESULT hr = pDeviceContext->Map(
                *ppBuffer,
                0,
                D3D11_MAP_WRITE_DISCARD,
                0,
                &mappedResource);

            byte* ppData = reinterpret_cast<byte*>(mappedResource.pData);

            for (uint64_t i = 0; i < fileSize; i += 0x10000)
            {
                DWORD readSize = min(fileSize - i, 0x10000);

                if (!ReadFile(
                    dataFile,
                    ppData,
                    readSize,
                    NULL,
                    NULL))
                {
                    uint32_t lastError = ::GetLastError();

                    CBR(lastError != ERROR_IO_PENDING);
                }
            }

            pDeviceContext->Unmap(
                *ppBuffer,
                0);

            D3D11_UNORDERED_ACCESS_VIEW_DESC uaView =
            {
                DXGI_FORMAT_UNKNOWN, // Format
                D3D11_UAV_DIMENSION_BUFFER, // ViewDimension
            };

            uaView.Buffer.FirstElement = 0;
            uaView.Buffer.Flags = 0;
            uaView.Buffer.NumElements = fileSize / sizeof(T);

            CHR(pDevice->CreateUnorderedAccessView(
                *ppBuffer,
                &uaView,
                ppUav));
        }
```

Why might I hr be E_INVALIDARG at the Map?

Note: FAILED and CHR are error checking macros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to create a buffer with your data.

If your data is a 2D texture, call [ID3D11Device::CreateTexture2D](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476521(v=vs.85).aspx). Don’t forget D3D11_BIND_UNORDERED_ACCESS in D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC::BindFlags field. And you can pass your `byte* pRawData` in the second argument, in that D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA structure.

If your data is 1D array of structures, call [ID3D11Device::CreateBuffer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476501(v=vs.85).aspx), again you should pass D3D11_BIND_UNORDERED_ACCESS, and your initial data.

There're other kinds of resources supported by UAVs: 1D textures, 1D texture arrays, 2D texture arrays, 3D textures. It all depends on your data, and on your shaders processing that.

Finally, call [ID3D11Device::CreateUnorderedAccessView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476523(v=vs.85).aspx) passing ID3D11Texture2D, or ID3D11Buffer, or some other resource. Both ID3D11Texture2D, ID3D11Buffer and others inherit from ID3D11Resource, so you can pass either of them.

<strike>**Update:** if you already have both created and you only need to update, call GetResource on your pDataView to get the resource from the view. Then to update the buffer ID3D11DeviceContext::Map, memcpy, ID3D11DeviceContext::Unmap. Just make sure you’ve created the resource allowing that, i.e. D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE.</strike>

**Update:** As said by the commenter, you can't directly update a UAV resource from the CPU. The solution? Create D3D11_USAGE_STAGING resource with D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE of the same format and dimensions, update it from the CPU using e.g. Map/Unmap, then call [ID3D11DeviceContext::CopyResource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476392(v=vs.85).aspx) to copy from staging resource to UA resource.

Comment: A CPU writable resource cannot use the uav binding, they are conflicting on PC. You have to keep a separate buffer and use a copy

Comment: @Soonts I was able to make it work as you described when creating the UAV with data, but wasn't so successful at updating the UAV's buffer once it was created.  Could you take a look and suggest what might be going wrong?